# Annoying Numlock bug in ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, numlock

I'm running Ubuntu on a laptop that doesn't have numlock.. and for some reason Ubuntu keep enabling numlock messing up my keyboard layout... u become 4, j become 1, m become 0... ect ect.

I been googling for 2 days and all I get is

```
    sudo xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = NoSymbol"
```

well if that work, I wont be asking this here. Can anyone teach me how to fix this stupid bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why it enables numlock on a laptop if you didn't tell it to do so.

Anyway, you can install the *numlockx* package. It should automatically stop numlock from being enabled since you have a laptop. If that isn't enough, open the `/etc/default/numlockx` file for editing and change the setting to `NUMLOCK=off`.